# Dock opaque in Yosemite

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

How do I make the dock, menus translucent in Yosemite? The upgrade from Mountain Lion on a Macbook 2010 seems to have remove the translucent look. The opaque look is what is there now.

Comment: What is the task bar on OS X? Note that the dock is still translucent, just less so and with more blur.

Comment: Is it possible to make the dock more translucent?

Answer (score 0):

Try [cdock](http://cdock.sourceforge.net) for both custom docks in Yosemite (and earlier) but primarily: the **transparent dock** again!

Answer (score 0):

In

```
System Preferences - Accessibility, Uncheck - Reduce Transparency
```

That should do it.